# floor sum of first $11$ terms of Harmonic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Value of $$\bigg\lfloor 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{11}\bigg\rfloor $$

Where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ Represent floor function of $x$.

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Plotting $\displaystyle y = f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ in Coordinate axis, We get

$$\int_1^{12}\frac{1}{x}dx<1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots + \frac{1}{11} <1+\int_{1}^{11}\frac{1}{x}dx$$

So we get

\begin{align}
\ln(12) & =2.303\log_{10}(12)<1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{11} \\[10pt]
& <1+\ln(11) =1+2.303\times \log_{10}(12)
\end{align}

How can i solve after that, Help Required, Thanks

Comment: You can just compute the quantity directly, since $1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/11 = 83711 / 27720 \approx 3.02$....

Comment: I have added like $1+0.5+.33+.125+.......,$ But getting $<3$.

Comment: Then it seems your computation is incorrect somewhere.

Comment: Your approximations by integrals may give away too much. You can do better with $1+\frac{1}{2}+\text{approximations}$. Maybe overkill for $11$.

Comment: The integral approximation will not be good enough here as the error between $\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{{\rm d}x}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{k}$ is $\sim \frac{1}{2k^2}$ which is quite large for all the terms. You need the total error to be smaller than $0.02$ to get the result. Just sum it! More fancy tecniques are going to take much more time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answer is $$H_{11} = \frac{83711}{27720} > 3$$ so the answer is $3$